# Автоматическое переключение табов на jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tabs

```js
$(function() {
  var item = $('.work__item');
  $(".work__inner-left").on("mouseenter", ".work__item:not(.active)", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this)
      .addClass("active")
      .siblings()
      .removeClass("active")
      .closest(".work__inner")
      .find(".work__inner-right__item")
      .removeClass("active")
      .eq($(this).index())
      .addClass("active");
  });
  $(".work__inner-left").on("click", ".work__item:not(.active)", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this)
      .addClass("active")
      .siblings()
      .removeClass("active")
      .closest(".work__inner")
      .find(".work__inner-right__item")
      .removeClass("active")
      .eq($(this).index())
      .addClass("active");
  });
  $(function() {
    var t = 1;

    function switchTabs() {
      if (t > 3) t = 1;
      if (t == 1) item[0].click();
      if (t == 2) item[1].click();
      if (t == 3) item[2].click();
      t++;
    }
    var sw_tabs_timer1 = window.setInterval(switchTabs, 5000);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="work__inner">
  <div data-wow-duration="2s" class="work__inner-left wow fadeInLeft">

    <div class="work__item active">
      <h3 class="work__item-title">Добавьте соцсети</h3>
      <div class="work__item-text">
        Привяжите к сервису свои аккаунты в социальных сетях: ВК, Instagram, Facebook и другие
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="work__item">
      <h3 class="work__item-title">Подготовьте контент</h3>
      <div class="work__item-text">
        Загрузите и отредактируйте фотографии. Посмотрите как будет выглядеть ваш пост в разных социальных сетях на разных устройствах.
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="work__item">
      <h3 class="work__item-title">Распланируйте посты</h3>
      <div class="work__item-text">
        С помощью удобного календаря распланируйте своих посты на месяц вперед.
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div data-wow-duration="2s" class="work__inner-right wow fadeInRight">
    <div class="work__inner-right__item active">
      <img src="img/work/ipad.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="work__inner-right__item">
      <img src="img/work/ipad1.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="work__inner-right__item">
      <img src="img/work/ipad2.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

В общем есть такой код на табы, они работают и переключаются каждые 5 сек, но как сделать что бы при выборе конкретного таба счетчик времени обнулился и заново шел 5 сек, а потом переходил к следующему табу, а не жил своей жизнью?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В примере интервал удаляется, когда мышка находится над элементом и запускается, когда уходит с элемента. 
См. комменты.

```js
$(function() {
    var item = $('.work__item');
    var t = 0; // активный эллемент
    var sw_tabs_timer1; //таймер
    
    //Ф-я запуска таймера
    const startTimer = () => {
        //установил интервал поменьше, чтобы быстрей проверять.
        sw_tabs_timer1 = window.setInterval(switchTabs, 1000);
    }       

    //Ф-я остановки таймера
    const stopTimer = () => {
        clearInterval(sw_tabs_timer1);
    }
    // эвент мышка уходит с элемента, запуск таймера.
    $(".work__inner-left").mouseleave(() => {
        startTimer();
    })
    
    //эвент - мышка над элементом, остановка таймера.
     $(".work__inner-left").mouseenter(()=>{
       stopTimer();
     });


    //запускаем таймер.
    startTimer();
    
    //чуть-чуть сократил, чтобы было попроще. 
    function switchTabs() {
        if (t > 2) t = 0;
          item[t].click();
        t++;
    }
    
    $(".work__inner-left").on("mouseenter", ".work__item:not(.active)", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //Указываем в t, какой элемент активный
        t=item.index(this);
        
        $(this)
            .addClass("active")
            .siblings()
            .removeClass("active")
            .closest(".work__inner")
            .find(".work__inner-right__item")
            .removeClass("active")
            .eq($(this).index())
            .addClass("active");
       
    });
    $(".work__inner-left").on("click", ".work__item:not(.active)", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
               
        $(this)
            .addClass("active")
            .siblings()
            .removeClass("active")
            .closest(".work__inner")
            .find(".work__inner-right__item")
            .removeClass("active")
            .eq($(this).index())
            .addClass("active");
    });
    //все, что было ниже, поднял вверх.

});
```

```css
.active {
background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="work__inner">
  <div data-wow-duration="2s" class="work__inner-left wow fadeInLeft">

    <div class="work__item active">
      <h3 class="work__item-title">Добавьте соцсети</h3>
      <div class="work__item-text">
        Привяжите к сервису свои аккаунты в социальных сетях: ВК, Instagram, Facebook и другие
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="work__item">
      <h3 class="work__item-title">Подготовьте контент</h3>
      <div class="work__item-text">
        Загрузите и отредактируйте фотографии. Посмотрите как будет выглядеть ваш пост в разных социальных сетях на разных устройствах.
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="work__item">
      <h3 class="work__item-title">Распланируйте посты</h3>
      <div class="work__item-text">
        С помощью удобного календаря распланируйте своих посты на месяц вперед.
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div data-wow-duration="2s" class="work__inner-right wow fadeInRight">
    <div class="work__inner-right__item active">
      <img src="img/work/ipad.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="work__inner-right__item">
      <img src="img/work/ipad1.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="work__inner-right__item">
      <img src="img/work/ipad2.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!!)))